# Excel Macro to Concatenate Rows of Variable Lengths with Delimiter

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I'm developing a worksheet users can fill out to generate a file that can be uploaded into SAP.

The worksheet will generate a mass upload of individual entries. Users will be asked to provide attributes for each line item they are requesting, which may vary based on the selection made (i.e. one row may have 5 attributes while the next may have 7).

I want to write a macro that will look at each row, starting from the top, and concatenate only the attribute columns (which are separated by two other columns in each instance) which are not blank and use a delimiter between each field.

I've been able to use some code I found through Microsoft to get the looping done (see below), but I can't figure out how to have the concatenate stop when a column is blank and then move to the next row.

```
Sub Submit()
Range("C2").Activate
Do While ActiveCell <> ""  

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).FormulaR1C1 = _
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) & "-" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) & "-" & 

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) & "-" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) & "-" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12) & "-" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15) & "-" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18)

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
End Sub
```

Right now, this code will take a five attribute entry and leave me with "1-2-3-4-5--", when I really want it to show up as "1-2-3-4-5".

Any thoughts on how I can go about doing this? Eventually, I want to be able to store those strings and populate them in a new workbook with some other information copied over from the original workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub Submit()

Dim c As Range, c2 As Range, v as String


Set c = Range("C2")
Do While c.Value <> ""  

    Set c2 = c
    v = ""
    Do While c2.value <> ""
        v = v & IIf(v <> "", "-", "") & c2.value
        Set c2 = c2.offset(0, 3)
    Loop
    c.offset(0, 21).Value = v

    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Had to make a correction. After the first loop, I set c2 = c again. Otherwise, the macro was offsetting by the end of the c2 offset before the loop cutoff.

Comment: My bad - should have been `c.offset(0, 21).Value = v`, not `c2.Offset()...`  Fixed.

Comment: Follow-up Question Tim: Let's say I wanted to change that "-" to a line break. Essentially, I'm going to create a single cell with wrapped text for a different view. How would I adjust the code to fix that? I know you can use CHAR(10) in normal concatenation. The express won't work if I just put the function in there (i.e. replace "-" with &CHAR(10)&). And if I replace "-" with "&CHAR(10)&" I would just get the actual text. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: `v = v & IIf(v <> "", vbLf, "") & c2.value`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Tim!

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick answer, so may not have everything you're after:

```
Public Function Submit(Target As Range) As String

    Dim sFinalOutput As String
    Dim rCell As Range

    'Cylce through each cell in your range.
    For Each rCell In Target

        'Look at the column number divided by 3 - if it's 0 then carry on.
        If rCell.Column Mod 3 = 0 Then
            If rCell.Value2 <> "" Then
                'Grab the value from the cell and add it to the final output.
                sFinalOutput = sFinalOutput & "-" & rCell.Value2
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    Submit = sFinalOutput

End Function
```

Use it in a formula such as:  `=submit(C4:L4)`

Comment: Thanks Darren! For this form, I don't think that will achieve everything, but I'm definitely saving that bit of code for later.